# Execution halted error in R terminal

Tags: r, cmd

I have use the following content in the testrscript.txt file.

```
getwd()
a <- 5 + 6
a
s
b<-10+20
b
```

I have use the following command to run this r script through command prompt

```
D:\>R.exe CMD BATCH testrscript.txt out.txt
```

After this command execution I got the following output in the out.txt

```
> getwd()
[1] "D:/"
> a <- 5 + 6
> a
[1] 11
> s
Error: object 's' not found
Execution halted
```

I expect the following output , i.e continue the execution after the error line execution instead of execution halted my expected out like below

```
> getwd()
[1] "D:/"
> a <- 5 + 6
> a
[1] 11
> s
Error: object 's' not found
> b<-10+20
> b
[1] 30
```

System information windows 8 64 bit machine
I have referred the following link to resolve this problem.
http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2009-July/000180.html
 But I cannot achieve this. How to continue the execution after the error line execution in r terminal?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, as per your link, you put `options(error=dump.frames)` in the first line of `testscript.txt`, and you still have a problem?

Comment: yes while setting options(error=dumb.frames) not working for me